# get data from two ajax queries utilise in a third function

Tags: c#, ajax

I have two `AJAX` calls which call c# functions.  These two functions get `datatables` and then return HTML to the client to display tables.

My current need is to access the two `datatables` before they are converted to html, which are inside these functions, **store** them somehow and then **re-use them in a third c# function** which can only be called after both AJAX calls have been completed.

I had considered storing these values in a `session` but this doesn't seem very clean as the tables could potentially be rather long (although not wide).

The ideal solution would be something like the following:

- Ajax call #1 -> c# function called -> saveDataSetInFunction(dataset1)
- Ajax call #2 -> c# function called -> saveDataSetInFunction(dataset2)
- btnClick -> c# function called to access both datatables which are available via the `saveDataSetInFunction` function.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you will need to store them somewhere in memory, thus it does not matter if you use session or some other way: cache, shared variable etc.

I would either store the tables in cache (`System.Runtime.Caching` - MS recommends using this for all caching needs) with a suitably short caching time or I would store the results in Session and make the third function remove the data from the session.

Answer (score 0):

You really only have 2 choices here:

1. Save data on server (Session, a temp file, a temp table in the database, etc...)
2. Send the entire data to the client and send it back to the server when needed

It's impossible to guess the best aproach without knowing the complete application, when choosing keep in mind:

- The amount of data to store/transfer
- The server load
- The client specs
- The bandwidth available